# Apache2 require login before presenting page of Jenkins

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, jenkins

I'm using Apache2 to proxy Jenkins to port 80 on my server.  The problem is, this server is open to the world so I want to set some sort of authentication so you have to login to get to the Jenkins page.

It's only for one user account so I don't need a db back end.  Just a flat-file with username and password or something like that for Apache to prompt for before it displays the page.

Jenkins is the only thing apache is presenting.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

For just one username and password, I'd go with the mod_auth_basic module. There's infromation about it at [apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html). It allows you to require users to enter username and password, which are stored in a htpwasswd file.